# Asking questions to emphasize a fact

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request, rhetorical-questions

In these contexts, I don't know how to ask a question to 
emphasize a fact. What tense or modal verb should I use( instead of ---marks)?

**1)He is the son of a millionaire. He doesn't have to work. Why -- he work?
   (I want to say there's no good reason for him to work)**

2)I have studied English for years and I'm going to take the TOEFL test. I have no reason to be worried about the test. Why--- be worried about it?

**3) My girlfriend has cheated on me several times. I'm going to break up with her. Why ---I trust her again?(I want to say it's absurd to trust her again. I have no good reason to trust her again)**

Thanks

Comment: You don't know **how** to ask, not **who** to ask. In the spirit of the question as asked, *Why w  I trust her again?*

Comment: @OmidKy These questions are called "rhetorical questions" - there's a tag for them if you'd like to add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the two modal verbs *would* or *should*.

> 1. He is the son of a millionaire. He doesn't have to work. Why ***should/would*** he work? (I want to say there's no good reason for him to work)
> 2. I have studied English for years and I'm going to take the TOEFL test. I have no reason to be worried about the test. Why ***should/would*** I be worried about it?
> 3. My girlfriend has cheated on me several times. I'm going to break up with her. Why ***should/would*** I trust her again?

Both are equally valid in these contexts, and the choice is up to your style.

In these contexts, *should* is the conditional auxiliary form of *shall*, and *would* is the conditional auxiliary form of *will*. There are other contexts where *should* is more correct than *would*, and vice versa, but in these cases they are both equally correct.

That being said, *should* is more commonly used in these contexts when we are heeding or expecting advice, or a sense of responsibility is commanded, whereas *would* is more commonly used to refer to *would* for unlikely or unreal premises.

**FYI:** the conditional auxiliary verbs, *should*, *could* and *would*, are correct in the first, second, third, singular and plural forms (I, you, he/she/it, you (plural), we (plural), they (plural))